# Why ThreadPoolExecutor finalize invokes shutdown and not shutdownNow

Tags: java, executorservice

Finalize method in class `ThreadPoolExecutor` Looks like below.

```
protected void finalize()  {
    shutdown();
}
```

Consider below program in which thread never terminates

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new SynchronousQueue<String>()
                        .put("will never get removed");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    executorService = null;
    System.gc();

}
```

In such case `shutdownNow` would have been better choice than `shutdown` at least JVM could have exited in that case.

**Update:**

Only possible explanation of why `finalize` calls `shutdown` method is if programmer does not call it explicitly it will get called while GC as a defensive mechanism. I see flaw in this mechanism since in above case JVM will not be terminated.

Answer (score 4):

First, let me ask you a question: Why would you need to pool a thread that never terminates? You pool objects to reuse them.

The reason why java calls shutdown, is to give the threads the oportunity to terminate gracefully.

If you need to run a thread in an infinite loop, then your thread should check that `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` returs false, and then return from `run()`.

In the example you show, you might want to use the method `offer()` with a timeout, rather and `put()`.

Wost case scenario, you can extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` and call `shutdownNow()` in the finalizer.

Comment: Updated the question. Question is if it is defensive mechanism why it is implemented that way?

Comment: It's not really a defensive mechanism, it's so the `ThreadPoolExecutor` would behave like any other java object, and when it's not reachable, it tell the threads to stop so it can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

The moral of this story is that if you want a ThreadPool to shutdown, you shouldn't be relying on finalize to do it.  This is true of any resource in Java, you should *never* depend on the finalization mechanism (as it may *never* run).  if you want a ThreadPool to shutdown, you should manage it yourself.

The `shutdown()` call in the finalize method is a reasonable compromise in the case that a programmer "accidentally" loses track of a ThreadPool.  the current tasks will run to completion, and then the pool will shutdown.  if `shutdownNow()` were used, at some random point in time (depending on the gc), your tasks would get interrupted.  probably less than ideal.  and, you can *always* create a task which refuses to shutdown regardless of whether `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` is invoked (just add a `while(true)` loop around the try/catch block in your example).

Answer (score 0):

When `shutdown()` is invoked, it means the pool will not accept new tasks and will actually "*shut down*" after the submitted tasks have been done. For your case, you'd better invoke `shutdownNow()` explicitly somewhere you want.