# Why does Java ThreadPoolExecutor override finalize()

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, threadpoolexecutor

I'd like to know why the ThreadPoolExecutor `finalize()` method invokes its shutdown() method when it is known that the finalize method only gets invoked by the GC **AFTER** all of its threads have been stopped.  So why does ThreadPoolExecutor override `finalize()` at all?

It seems misleading to me (and a source of a thread-leak my project) that `ThreadPoolExecutor.finalize()` invokes shutdown() as this gives the strong (but false) impression that 
- ThreadPoolExecutor manages the lifecycle of its threads and will stop the threads when the GC collects the ThreadPoolExecutor object
- it is only necessary to invoke shutdown() or shutdownNow() if you want deterministic results as opposed to relying on the GC to tidy up (obviously, poor practice to do this!)

Notes
In this thread, [why-doesnt-this-thread-pool-get-garbage-collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728102/why-doesnt-this-thread-pool-get-garbage-collected) Affe explains why it is still necessary for the client to invoke `shutdown()`

In this thread, [why-threadpoolexecutor-finalize-invokes-shutdown-and-not-shutdownnow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545279/why-threadpoolexecutor-finalize-invokes-shutdown-and-not-shutdownnow) the originator is puzzled by this topic but the answers aren't as comprehensive as in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728102/why-doesnt-this-thread-pool-get-garbage-collected)

The [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for `ThreadPoolEecutor.finalize()` do include the words "and it has no threads" but this is easily overlooked.

Comment: I agree here that the documentation of `finalize()` is rather confusing... I wonder how a `.newFixedThreadPool()` can have "no threads".

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor's JavaDocs have a Finalization section that explains " If you would like to ensure that unreferenced pools are reclaimed even if users forget to call shutdown(), then you must arrange that unused threads eventually die, by setting appropriate keep-alive times, using a lower bound of zero core threads and/or setting allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean). ".  Therefore, it is possible for the thread count to reduce and reach zero.

Answer (score 3):

First, if you think this is a bug, then report it to Oracle.

Second, we cannot definitely answer your question, because you are essentially asking "why did they design it this way" ... and we weren't there when they made the decision.

But I suspect the reason is that the current choice was deemed to be the lesser of two evils:

- On the one hand, if you a threadpool *could* be shutdown merely because it was no longer directly referenced, then threads that are doing real work could be terminated prematurely.
- On the other hand, as you observed a threadpool that doesn't get automatically shutdown on becoming on longer directly reachable could be a memory leak.

Given that there are clearly ways to avoid the storage leak, I think that the 2nd alternative (i.e. the current behaviour) is the lesser of the evils.

Anyway, there is a clear evidence that this behaviour was considered by the designers; i.e. this quotation from the `ThreadPoolExecutor` javadoc:

> **Finalization**
>
> A pool that is no longer referenced in a program AND has no remaining threads will be shutdown automatically. If you would like to ensure that unreferenced pools are reclaimed even if users forget to call `shutdown()`, then you must arrange that unused threads eventually die, by setting appropriate keep-alive times, using a lower bound of zero core threads and/or setting `allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)`.

(And that sort of answer's @fge's comment.  It happens when inactive worker threads are configured to time out.)

I also think there is an implementation-based reason as well.  Take a look at the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker).

Each thread in the thread pool has a reference to a Runnable, which is actually an instance of the inner class `ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker`.  This means that there is a strong reference path from the (live, though probably idle) `Thread` to the `ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker` object, and from that object to the enclosing `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance.  And since live threads are always reachable, a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance is remains reachable until all of its threads actually terminate.

Now I/we can't tell you which came first, the behaviour or the javadoc specification.  See my "Secondly ..." point above ...

But, like I said above ("Firstly ..."), if you think this is a bug, report it to Oracle.   And the same goes if you think that the javadoc is misleading ... though I think your argument there is weak given the material that I quoted.

---

As to why they overloaded `finalize()` to call `shutdown()` if `shutdown()` does nothing in this circumstance:

- it may have done something significant in earlier versions, and
- the `shutdown()` method ends by calling a hook method that is apparently overridden in subclasses to do something significant ... according to the comments.

Comment: I don't think that there is a bug in the implementation or the JavaDocs.  E.g. The threadpool must not be stopped while it has work to do.  My question is simply "why did the designers choose to override finalize()" and I think that your answer is that you don't know ... ie that you don't think that invoking shutdown() in the context of the GC thread does anything useful.

Comment: As explaining in the post, the fact that finalize is overriden in order to invoke shutdown() was misunderstood by senior developers to mean an advantage of using ThreadPookExecutor is that it manages the life-cycle of the threads.  I can't argue with Oracle that overriding finalize() is a bug because they describe the "no threads" condition.   Anyhow, thanks for taking the time to rely.

Comment: @Diarmuid - What can I say?  Maybe the senior developers just need to read the javadocs more carefully ... especially if >>you<< are not even prepared to say the javadocs are misleading!  (Note: IMO if the javadoc is misleading, that *would* be a bug.  And saying that the javadocs are misleading and not reporting that to Oracle is a cop out.)